# C# Regex to match a string that has double bars that are not in quotation marks

Tags: c#, regex

I am getting crazy on this! I would like to extract every part of a string that is surrounded by double curly brackets but is not inside a single quotation.

So when `"{{Test}} '{{hello}}' {{what}} {that}}"`

The result would be:

```
{{Test}}
{{what}}
```

**Update:**

With this I am getting all parts that are surrounded by double curly brackets:

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"(\{\{.+?\}\})")
```

**Update 2:**

Not realy beautifull but I think this works:

```
var removedQuotationParts = Regex.Replace(input, @"(['].+?['])", "");

var parts = Regex.Matches(removedQuotationParts, @"(\{\{.+?\}\})")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the links, I am working on it.. The sad thing is that I have read so many time tutorials, but it does not remain in my mind :-D

Comment: `{{.*?}}` is a simple pattern matching any string between two strings. The best trick ever will help you solve the issue.

Comment: It is easier, `var parts = Regex.Matches(input, @"'[^']*'|({{.*?}})").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();`, https://ideone.com/4nbUxr

Comment: Thanks for sharing your improvement!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [Best Trick Ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick), namely, match any text inside apostrophes, and then match *and capture* your expected pattern.

A possible regex will look like

```
'[^']*'|({{.*?}})
```

It matches

- `'[^']*'` - `'`, then any 0+ chars other than `'` and then a `'`
- `|` - or
- `({{.*?}})` - Capturing group 1: `{{`, any 0+ chars, as few as possible (including newlines due to `RegexOptions.Singleline` option, see code below), then `}}`.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/4nbUxr):

```
var input = "{{Test}} '{{hello}}' {{what}} {that}}";
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"'[^']*'|({{.*?}})", RegexOptions.Singleline)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    .ToList(); 
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
{{Test}}
{{what}}
```

NOTE: `.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))` is necessary to omit all those matches where Group 1 did not match.